# Plotting a logisitc regression superimposed over a probability chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science, logistic-regression

I want to build a chart similar to this[image: logistic regression superimposed over a bar chart]

I have created a bar chart, and I have the logistic regression completed.

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

plt.bar(prob_df['diff'], prob_df['full_win_prob'])
plt.show()
```

[image: my current barplot]

```
#logistic regression
X = dfx['home_diff'].values
y = dfx['away_win'].values
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X, y)

print(logreg.intercept_, logreg.coef_)
[-0.67032214] [[0.04948131]] #results
```

I have the chart and I have the model, I can't figure out how to plot the model on top of the chart, its a bit frustrating I'm sure the answer is simple. I would prefer an answer in matplotlib but seaborn is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yy = logreg.predict_proba(XX)[:,1]` to plot the logistic curve for an array of x-values.  `logreg.predict_proba(XX)[:,0]` gives the inverted curve, the probability of being `0`. `logreg.predict(XX)` gives the predictions, i.e. the logistic curve rounded to 0 or 1.

Here is an example starting from some generated test data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
# logistic regression
X = np.random.uniform(1, 9, 20)  # dfx['home_diff'].values
y = np.random.choice([0, 1], 20, p=[0.8, 0.2])
y = np.where(X < 5, y, 1 - y)  # dfx['away_win'].values
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y, color='black', label='Given values')
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X, y)
XX = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
prediction = logreg.predict(XX)
probability_0, probability_1 = logreg.predict_proba(XX).T

plt.plot(XX[:, 0], prediction, color='limegreen', lw=2, alpha=0.7, label='Predicted values')
plt.plot(XX[:, 0], probability_0, color='crimson', lw=2, alpha=0.7, ls='--', label='Probability of being 0')
plt.plot(XX[:, 0], probability_1, color='deepskyblue', lw=2, alpha=0.7, label='Probability of being 1')
plt.legend()
```

[image: logistic curve]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JohanCs help I was able to get it. Clearly my answer is heavily inspired by his posting. I adjusted the code a bit so it displays the model over the bar graph rather than the scatterplot. I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough karma.

Here is what I used and the result:

```
# logistic regression
X = dfx['home_diff'].values
y = dfx['away_win'].values
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X, y)
prediction = logreg.predict(X)
probability_0, probability_1 = logreg.predict_proba(X).T



plt.plot(X[:, 0], probability_1, color='blue', lw=2, alpha=0.6, label='Probability of being 1')
plt.bar(prob_df['diff'], prob_df['full_win_prob'], color='orange')

plt.legend()
```

[image: resolution]